# Sending/receiving data to/from a USB sensor

Tags: c#, .net, usb

I have a project in which I have to show the output of sensor signals graphically. 
To do this, I want to send the sensor data to the PC via USB, then read that data using .NET.

The USB signal is a stream of sensor data. How can I read & write to the sensor?

Comment: What hardware? Doest it have a driver or is it HID? Do you have an API?

Comment: Use a libusb .NET wrapper.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: i have to implement it on windows

Comment: they are providing me data in USB

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: it is HID

Comment: you can use libusb http://sourceforge.net/projects/libusbdotnet/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into this it might help: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/USB_HID.aspx